# And Select stops working in mobile phones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, responsive-design, antd

I have a Modal with Form inside. Form has Select fields and in mobile devices Select dropdown does not work. When I click on Select field dropdown shows for a second and hides.

My code sample:

```
    <Modal
      title={t("filters")}
      open={props.isOpened}
      footer={null}
      centered
      onCancel={props.onClose}>
      <Row justify="space-between">
        <Col className="is-width-100pct">
          <Row className="mb-3" justify="space-between">
            <Typography>{t("department")}</Typography>
            <Checkbox onChange={selectAllDepartments} checked={isAllDepartmentSelected}>. {t("selectAll")}</Checkbox>
          </Row>
          <Select
             getPopupContainer={(triggerNode: HTMLElement) => 
               (triggerNode?.parentNode as HTMLElement) || document.body}
            mode="multiple"
            allowClear
            filterOption={handleFilterOptions}
            onChange={setDepartmentIds}
            className="is-width-100pct"
            maxTagCount={5}
            value={departmentIds}
            options={departmentOptions}/>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row justify="end" className="mt-5">
        <Col>
          <Button onClick={props.onClose}>{t("cancel")}</Button>
        </Col>
        <Col className="ml-5">
          <Button type="primary" onClick={handleConfirm}>{t("confirm")}</Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Modal>
```

I upgraded my ant design wersion to 5.9.3 but it’s not working(

Comment: Make sure the z-index of the dropdown menu is higher than other elements in the modal or on the page. If it's behind other elements, it may appear to show briefly and then hide